# How to parse such a JSON to NSDictionary and get the keys and values

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

```
[
 {
"week": "1-16",
"course": "math",
"lecturer:": "AAA",
"credit": "2"   },
{
"week": "9-16",
"course": "tech",
"lecturer:": "BBB",
"credit": "2"   },
{
"week": "1-8",
"course": "English",
"lecturer:": "CC",
"credit": "0.5"   },
{
"week": "1-16",
"course": "German",
"lecturer:": "DDD",
"credit": "4"   }
]
```

I 've got such a JSON  and I've parse it to a NSDictionary using the following code

```
NSDictionary *resultDic = [NSJSerialization JSONObjectWithData:resData         options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
```

but when I try to get the value from the keys of NSDictionary , an error occurs
I found there is no key in the NSDictionary.

So how can I get the value using ObjectForKey 
Thanks

Comment: Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  (It only takes 5-10 minutes.)  Then you will see that what you have is an array containing "objects" (dictionaries).

Comment: And it's "NSJSONSerialization", not "NSJSerialization".

Answer (score 2):

`resultDic` would be an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary itself. You want something like this:

```
NSArray * resultArray = [NSJSONerialization JSONObjectWithData:resData   options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSDictionary * result = [resultArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * week = [result objectForKey:@"week"];
```